# WP8 Multiple projects share code by Windows Phone Class Library, but can't share AppResources.resx

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, localization

Let's say I have 3 projects: `LibClassProj`, `Proj1` and `Proj2` in windows phone develompment by c#.  `Proj1` and `Proj2` share the code in `LibClassProj`.  It works fine.  Now the problem is, I can't get the string in `LibClassProj`'s AppResources.resx from `Proj1` or `Proj2`'s xaml.

For instance, this is part of the xaml from `LibClassProj`.

```
SelectableButtonText="{
                    Binding Path=LocalizedResources.strTestButtonTitleClose, 
                    Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

When I put `strTestButtonTitleClose` in LibClassProj's AppResources.resx file, I can't get this string from `Proj1` or `Proj2`(It means set `Proj1` or `Proj2` as StartUp project).  If I put it in `Proj1`'s AppResources.resx, I can get it  when I choose `Proj1` as StartUp  project.  The same to `Proj2`.

Anyone know how can I just put the string only in `LibClassProj`'s AppResources.resx, and I can get access to it from other projects?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference that shared resource from each project's App.xaml:

```
<Application
    ...
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:YourApp.LibClassProj;assembly=YourApp.LibClassProj">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <lib:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you should be able to use the strings like you mentioned in both Proj1 and Proj2:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.strTestButtonTitleClose}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I stried this and it can't find LocalizedStrings.  YourApp Here: `xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:YourApp.LibClassProj;assembly=YourApp.LibClassProj"` do you mean Proj1.LibClassProj?

Comment: Does "Proj1.LibClassProj" exist? My understanding was that you had "LibClassProj", "Proj1" and "Proj2". My suggestion is to define xmlns:lib in each of Proj1 & Proj2, and it points to LibClassProj. This allows strings from LibClassProj to be used in Proj1 & Proj2.

Comment: Hi @mleroy, I understand what you mean.  I'm just a little confused about what it should be of **YourApp** in my situation, I only have the 3 projects in VS: `LibClassProj`, `Proj1` and `Proj2`.  `LibClassProj` has been added to `Proj1` and `Proj2`'s References.

Comment: If the namespace of your project is just "LibClassProj", then this should work: 

xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:LibClassProj;assembly=LibClassProj"

Comment: Hi mleroy, still not work:  Error 1 `The tag 'LocalizedStrings' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:LibClassProj;assembly=LibClassProj'`  Are you sure it works for you?

Comment: I created a sample solution with 3 projects to show how I have it working. Let me know if this setup does not match your requirement. http://sdrv.ms/1mcms10

Comment: Hi mleroy, your sample is exactly what I want!  Thank you very much for your kind help! I made a stupid mistake when I tried your solution before your sample.  It saves my time.  Thank you again.